# Localization: How to allow the user to define custom resources without compiling?

Tags: wpf, localization, resources, resx

In our application, we have a collection of data items, each with a `DisplayedName` property. This property should be localized, i.e. it should be displayed in the language selected by the user. Therefore, another property, `DisplayedNameResourceKey`, specifies which resource should be returned by the `DisplayedName` property.

In simplified code this means something like this:

```
public string DisplayedName
{
    get
    {
        return MyResources.ResourceManager.GetObject(this.DisplayedNameResourceKey);
    }
}

public string DisplayedNameResourceKey
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Now, the problem is: The user should be able to edit these items including the `DisplayedName`, or more precisely the `DisplayedNameResourceKey`. And not only this, but the user should also be able to somehow define new resources which he can then reference. That is, he can either choose from a predefined set of resources (some commonly used names), or define a custom resource which then needs to be localized by the user as well.

However, the user cannot add custom resources to `MyResources` at runtime and without compiling. Therefore, another approach is needed. It does not have to be an extremely user-friendly way (e.g. UI is not required) because this will typically be done by our service engineers.

I was thinking about using a txt or csv file containing pairs of resource keys and the corresponding translations. A separate file would exist for every language at a predefined location. But I am not really satisfied with that idea because it involves a lot of work to resolve the resources.

Does anyone know a good approach for such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider putting the resources in a database. In this way, you keep it fairly dynamic and fast.

E.g. a table with 3 columns: resource key, language, message. You should probably create a composite index on the resource key and language columns for fast lookup.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, our software does not involve any database functionality so far. And I do not think that we will introduce this functionality just for this special purpose. Maybe I should have mentioned that in my original post, sorry.